# Using Outlook, is there a way to definitely destroy an email?

Tags: email, outlook, erase

I have to delete an email from Outlook. But not just from Outlook: from my computer, from the Earth.

Of course I can't delete it from the computer of its receiver; but what I need is that if a computer expert goes on my pc, there can be absolutely no way that he can recover it.

I assume that deleting the mail even from the trash is not enough, right? So what should I do?

Comment: After a "HARD delete" the email is deleted from the local PST/OST - it completely bypassed any "Deleted Items" folder and is *gone*. Assuming that such never came from, or was never sent to, another server (this includes being connected via Exchange, even if the mail was "never sent"!) then it is gone from the application and data viewpoint. Advanced forensics tools can still recover "residue" from the filesystem .. anyway, Off Topic.

Comment: Get a good lawyer who can credibly claim that the email was planted? :-)

Answer (score 0):

If your using outlook with exchange, that depends on the exchange server retention policy. If you hard delete an item (delete and delete again from deleted items) you can still recover it if there's a retention policy.

Cleanse the retention list by going to (Folder -> Recover Deleted Items) and select the email there and click delete. However there' still a way to retrieve it by an exchange administrator for a number of days (14 by default).

EDIT: But the mail will NOT be on your computer, it will be retrievable from the server only.